# Import duration from CSV

Tags: r, duration

I have a CSV file that has the call records like Time of the call, Called number, Duration of the call etc that I want to import into R.

The format of 'Duration of the call' field in the CSV file is something like 1d02:03:04 ie 1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes and 4 seconds.

I can easily convert the Duration field to Duration object in Python Pandas with `df.duration = pd.to_timedelta(df.duration)`.
After conversion, I can get the stop time by adding the start time with the duration.

I am looking for equivalent of the same in R to convert 1d02:03:04 as duration object so that I can get the end time.

Comment: Look at the `lubridate` package in R. There's a function called `interval`. Could be a starting point for you

Comment: There's `lubridate::as.duration`

Comment: @Arun welcome to SO! :) Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. You can use `dput()` for easily showing us a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can also use `regex` for this (even though other solutions e.g. `lubridate` might be better):

First create the pattern `^(\\d*)d(\\d*):?(\\d*):?(\\d*)$` (that might need to be adapted to your formats) to extract the days, hours, minutes and seconds of the durations. Then with this information you can add to your start times.

```
fun = function (start_time, duration) {
  # Check start_time
  if (!'POSIXct' %in% class(start_time))
    stop('Expect "start_time" to be of class "POSIXct"')

  # Regex pattern for extraction of days, hours, minutes & seconds
  pattern = '^(\\d*)d(\\d*):?(\\d*):?(\\d*)$'

  # Extract data
  days    = as.integer(gsub(pattern, '\\1', duration))
  hours   = as.integer(gsub(pattern, '\\2', duration))
  minutes = as.integer(gsub(pattern, '\\3', duration))
  seconds = as.integer(gsub(pattern, '\\4', duration))
  # Maybe add some safety measures just in case e.g. ifelse(is.na(seconds ), 0L, seconds)

  # Add (in seconds)
  final_time = start_time + seconds + minutes*60 + hours*60*60 + days*60*60*24
  return (final_time)
}
```

Here a small example with vectors

```
durations = c('1d02:03:04', '2d02:03:04', '10d02:03:04')
start_times = rep(Sys.time(), 3L)
fun(start_time = start_times, duration = durations)
# [1] "2019-06-11 11:02:19 CEST" "2019-06-12 11:02:19 CEST" "2019-06-20 11:02:19 CEST"
```

Comment: Hi Niko.. I was expecting a single line code like in python. However you solution is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The chron `times` class represents a duration as days and fraction of a day.  We define two functions to convert from our custom text format to `times` and from `times` to our custom text format.

```
library(chron)
text2times <- function(x) with(read.table(text = as.character(x), sep = "d", as.is = TRUE),
  V1 + times(V2))
times2text <- function(x) paste(as.integer(x), format(x %% 1), sep = "d") 

dd <- transform(d, diffdays = text2times(stop) - text2times(start),
                   difftext = times2text(text2times(stop) - text2times(start)))
```

giving:

```
       start       stop diffdays   difftext
1 1d02:03:04 2d02:03:50 1.000532 1d00:00:46
```

### S3 custom class dur

This may be overkill for what you need but we could define an S3 class `dur` to do this.

```
as.dur <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("as.dur")
as.dur.character <- function(x, ...) structure(text2times(x), class = c("dur", "times"))
as.dur.factor <- function(x, ...) as.dur(as.character(x))
format.dur <- function(x, ...) times2text(times(x))

# new it's easy
transform(d, diff = as.dur(stop) - as.dur(start))
```

giving:

```
       start       stop       diff
1 1d02:03:04 2d02:03:50 1d00:00:46
```

### Using dur in read.table

We can also read the data straight into `dur` class

```
setAs("character", "dur", function(from) as.dur(from))

# test input - normally read from file but to keep answer self contained use string
Lines <- "start stop
1d02:03:04 2d02:03:50"

# now it's even easier
dd <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, colClasses = c("dur", "dur"))
transform(dd, diff = stop - start)
##        start       stop       diff
## 1 1d02:03:04 2d02:03:50 1d00:00:46
```

### Note

Sample input in reproducible form:

```
d <- data.frame(start = "1d02:03:04", stop = "2d02:03:50")
```